# python multithread and strangeTypeError: takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

```
def crawler(id):
    print id
    crawer.getCourseFromUrl("http://www.imooc.com/view/"+id)
    time.sleep(3)
def main():
    print '*** Starting crawler ***'
    try:
        for id in xrange(100):
            threads = []
            for i in range(10):
                t = threading.Thread(target = crawler,args = str(i+1))
                threads.append(t)
            for t in threads:
                t.start()
            for t in threads:
                t.join()
            for t in threads:
                t.close()
    except:
        pass
    print '*** crawler End ***'
```

Above is my code, and when args is 1 to 9, it works well, but when it comes to 10 and larger it comes to the error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-10:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
TypeError: crawler() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I could not figure out what it's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thread` gets `args` and use it with function this way:

```
crawler(args[0], args[1], ...)
```

When `str(i+1)` has only one char it gives

```
crawler(args[0])
```

When `str(i+1)` has two chars it gives

```
crawler(args[0], args[1])
```

but your functions expects only one argument.

You have to use list or tuple in `Thread`

```
Thread(target = crawler,args = [ str(i+1) ] )

Thread(target = crawler,args = ( str(i+1), ) )
```

and then `args[0]` will get all `str(i+1)` as one element.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass args as a tuple:

```
t = threading.Thread(target = crawler, args = (str(i+1),))
```

As documented here https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread